# Valuation of a rational function under pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Today, I have a rather simple question, although I can't find the answer.
Let $Y'\subset Y$ be a subvariety with embedding $\Phi:Y'\hookrightarrow Y$ and $f\in K(Y)$ a rational function. Is the following true?
$\nu_{P}(f)=\nu_{\Phi^{*}(P)}(\Phi^{*}(f)),\,P\in Y$, where $\nu$ is the valuation.

Comment: $\Phi^*(f)$ isn't a well-defined element of $K(Y')$, so no valuation is well-defined.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should also mention the things that are special in my case. $Y$ is a toric variety, so $f=\chi^{m}$. Also $Y'$ lives in the torus of $Y$ $T_{Y}$. It seemed to work in my example..

Comment: If $A$ is an integral domain and $I \subseteq A$ is a prime ideal, then there is no natural map $Q(A) \to Q(A/I)$. You cannot restrict rational functions to closed subschemes. I'm not sure, but in the context of toric varieties this should be the same.

Comment: @Richard:This is correct if $Y'$ is an open dense subset of $Y$ as in the settings of toric varietis in your comment. Because the canonical map $K(Y)\to K(Y')$ is then an isomorphism.